# Making Android studio emulator accessible from the web in Windows

Tags: android, grpc, emulation

What is the simplest way of achieving this ? It it possible in linux using docker and a gRPC proxy like Envoy as it is explained here https://github.com/google/android-emulator-container-scripts
Is there a solution like this in windows ?